# Repeat Integer Input and Print ; Then Repeat Input and Print

Tags: python

```
q = int(input("How many numbers do you need to check? "))
dt = 0
ndt = 0

for i in range(q):
    w = int(input("Enter number: "))
if w % 3 == 0:
    print("{} is divisible by 3.".format(w))
    dt = dt + 1
else:
    print("{} is not divisible by 3.".format(w))
    ndt = ndt + 1
print("You entered {} number(s) that are divisible by 3".format(dt))
print("You entered {} number(s) that are not divisible by 3".format(ndt))
```

I'd like my ask the user to "Enter number" and then after it'll subsequently answer if it divisible by three or not.

Ex:

```
"Enter number: 6"
"6 is divisible by 3"
"Enter number: 9"
"9 is divisible by 3"
"Enter number: 11"
"11 is not divisible by 3"

"You entered 2 number(s) that are divisible by 3"
"You entered 1 number(s) that are not divisible by 3"
```

I truly haven't really tried anything.

Comment: Indent your `if/else` block so that it is in the `for` loop. Right now you are only running it after the `for` loop finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just your tabbing that needs to be changed. To get your if statement inside the loop it needs to be tabbed to the correct position.

```
q = int(input("How many numbers do you need to check? "))
dt = 0
ndt = 0

for i in range(q):
    w = int(input("Enter number: "))
    if w % 3 == 0:
        print("{} is divisible by 3.".format(w))
        dt = dt + 1
    else:
        print("{} is not divisible by 3.".format(w))
        ndt = ndt + 1
print("You entered {} number(s) that are divisible by 3".format(dt))
print("You entered {} number(s) that are not divisible by 3".format(ndt))
```

Comment: ^ Thanks, it was the tabbing that was the issue!

Comment: No worries! If the answer solved your problem then marking it as an accepted answer is appreciated @ShaneHarris